# checker framework: Supress Warnings in default constructor

Tags: checker-framework

I have two constructors: normal ctor which initialises the object properly and a second default ctor for Hibernate which generates initialize fields warnings. What's the preferred way to get rid of the warnings?

```
package test;

public class Example {
    String x;

    public Example(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    Example() {
        // Ctor for Hibernate, warnings generated here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention looking in the documentation, so I'm not sure whether you have done so.  The [Checker Framework manual](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html) contains a chapter titled ["Suppressing warnings"](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#suppressing-warnings), which might contain all the information you need.

The most common approach is to write a [@SuppressingWarnings annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), which is the standard way to suppress warnings from the Java compiler.

You should write it on the smallest program element possible (such as a local variable declaration rather than the whole constructor or class), and you should supply the most specific key possible.  The reason is to avoid accidentally suppressing more warnings than you intended.

Comment: I did go though the documentation and found the Suppressing warnings section. I couldn't get it to work but have just worked out that it's not a @SuppressWarnings("notnull") but a @SuppressWarnings("initialize") to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  It can be helpful to post the actual code and error message when you ask a question; that would have indicated the issue.  The @SuppressWarnings key is given at the beginning of the error message.

Comment: That leaves a problem that you have to disable checking for 'unhandled token in SupressWarnings' which I normally have set to "Warning" in Eclipse which is a shame but not the end of the world.

I was wondering if I could do anything with the initialization qualifiers which I haven't figure out yet.

Thanks BTW! Much appreciated

Comment: You can either disable all the "Unhandled Token in @SuppressWarnings'' warnings in Eclipse, or you can write `@SuppressWarnings` annotations related to the Checker Framework [in comments](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#annotations-in-comments).